# Credit Memo for Grand Total is Zero

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I have magento 1.9.2.3. I have an order for which grand total is 0 and its status is complete. When I am going to create its credit memo, system didn't give an option to create a credit memo.

I just edit the order and give custom price 0 and create the order.

Can some one let me know how can I create a credit memo?

Thanks

Comment: In case, Grand Total is 0, you can only cancel the order. Refunds (credit memos) are allowed only for the orders with positive grand total, not zero.

Comment: thanks for answer. i am also unable to cancel the order because its status is complete. can you please let me know how can i cancel the order.

Answer (score 3):

Its blocked in the Code. If the total paid amount is smaller the 0.0001, then you can't create a Credit Memo.

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

```
if (abs($this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getTotalPaid()) - $this->getTotalRefunded()) < .0001) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way how can i restock the products? actually i want to restock the products by credit memo or anything else procedure?

Comment: There are other files to hack : `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php:649` and `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php:372` and `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreditmemoController.php:280`. Moreover, you should not create creditmemo of 0. It is not logic. If you want manage the return, use a RMA module for it.